# Monotouch - Windows Azure toolkit

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios

I am working on an Iphone application which needs a direct access to Azure. I know there are toolkit versions exist for Objective C and Android. Is there any ported version of the toolkit exists for Monotouch?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? "access to Azure"? SQL, blob, tables, queues, service bus, services hosted on compute nodes?

Comment: I am trying to access the Azure table storage.

Comment: just reading or adding data as well? Would consuming the REST API ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179423.aspx ) from mono(touch) be a solution? I don't think there is a mono-compatible SDK around ... at least not for azure tables .. blobs, queues, sql has seen some open source efforts ( https://github.com/richorama/azure-sdk-for-mono ) ...

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific Azure SDK which is designed for MonoTouch and the Azure desktop binary are not compatible. If you decide to use MonoTouch, you would need to use WebClient API to create your own HTTP/HTTPS connection something similar to as described [here](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2011/12/cross-devicecross-location-pub-sub-using-windows-azure-service-bus-topics-subscriptions-in-ios-with-monotouch.html), which could be comparative complex. On internet you may find some experiment level code to use Azure services and MonoTouch application so you may be by your own to try to get things working.

If you choose Objective C then you can use iOS SDK for Windows Azure which is far better solution. I personally will not use MonoTouch to develop application on iOS devices, if I am heavily dependent on Windows Azure Services, instead I will choose iOS Windows Azure SDK to connect Azure Service through native code.

Check this out as well: [MonoTouch connect to Azure ACS, Azure SQL / Azure WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882159/monotouch-connect-to-azure-acs-azure-sql-azure-wcf/10885414#10885414)